# Print current date, without complex time commands

Tags: c, date

The prompt is:

Implement a function that determines and prints out the current year, month and day.

For example:

Today is 03/04/2014.

You guys dont have to really mind the code i wrote, its just kinda like scribble trying to figure our a way to print the current date using the seconds since the epoch given by the
time(NULL) command.

Before anyone gives me a super complex time command code etc etc, im pretty sure my professor wants us to convert the unix time (seconds since the epoch: jan 1, 1970) to the current date somehow.

Would anyone be able to help me in anyway to do this in the way my professor wants?

Thanks!

The code i currently have is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
int days, weeks, months, years, option, rmd, currentyear, currentmonth;
time_t seconds;

seconds = time(NULL);

days = seconds/(60*60*24);
weeks = seconds/((60*60*24)*7);
rmd=seconds%31557600;
months = ((seconds/31557600) * 12)+(((float)rmd/31557600)*12);
years = days/(365.25);

currentyear = 1970 + years;
currentmonth = (((float)rmd/31557600)*12)+1;



printf("%ld/%ld", currentmonth,currentyear);
;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have asked [several similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3436065/user3436065?tab=questions&sort=votes), are any of the answers helpful to you that you could accept? And don't use **C beginner help** in your title anymore, instead, tag the question with `c`.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with dates the naive way is a suicide*, use the `localtime` function. It will still get something wrong (dates are a [horrible hideous mess](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time) that just cannot be got completely right), but at least the "nornal" stuff is already taken care of, and it's someone else's fault anyhow.

*your code is not handling leap years, so your result  is completely wrong. So you add the code to check for years multiple if four. But then dates before 1900 are wrong, because century boundaries are an exception (they aren't leap years). And then dates after 2000 are all wrong, because there's an exception to the exception, and years divisible by 400 are leap years anyway. And we haven't started talking about time zones, DST and leap seconds.

Comment: The calculation is good between 1901 and 2099...that is, the 100-year rule doesn't apply to any date in that range.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: ok, now go calculate dates before 1918 in Russia with those rules (also, I'm quite sure there's some mess between 1918 and 1930).

Comment: There are endless sets of possible calendars.  For more information, check out [The Calendarists](http://calendarists.com/).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    time_t now = time(0);
    struct tm *t = localtime(&now);

    printf("%.4d-%.2d-%.2d\n", t->tm_year + 1900, t->tm_mon + 1, t->tm_mday);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for asnwersing but... i dont think im allowed to use pointers and time functions...

Comment: Have fun then...but that's the simple way to do it without using complex time calculations.